# How to uninstall redundant version of python3

Tags: python, macos, pip, package, homebrew

The situation I face is that I **seem** to have two `python3.6`s on my MacBook Pro, one with the `.dmg` installer from the official `python` website, and one installed via Homebrew ( inferred by others, I don't remember whether it is right or not) :

```
TreaserdeMacBook-Pro:~ treasersmac$ python3
Python 3.6.0 (v3.6.0:41df79263a11, Dec 22 2016, 17:23:13) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sys
>>> print(sys.path)
'['', 
'/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python36.zip', 
'/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6', 
'/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/lib-
dynload', '/Users/treasersmac/Library/Python/3.6/lib/python/site-packages',
 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-
packages']
```

And this brings a result that even some packages have been successfully installed  through `pip3`, they cannot be imported to `python3` successfully, like:

```
TreaserdeMacBook-Pro:~ treasersmac$ pip3 install beautifulsoup4
Collecting beautifulsoup4
Downloading beautifulsoup4-4.6.0-py3-none-any.whl (86kB)
100% |████████████████████████████████| 92kB 4.3kB/s 
Installing collected packages: beautifulsoup4
Successfully installed beautifulsoup4-4.6.0
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bs4'
```

the same for the module Pillow, [Installed Pillow but still get : ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PIL'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48249425/installed-pillow-but-still-get-modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-pil) 
It is @hoefling that points out that I may have too many versions of `python3.6`.
Therefore, I think it reasonable to remove one of them.

Actually, I have no idea why there are two of them, and the time I began to learn and install python was about 2 years ago, so I cannot recall the details( that's why I use '**seem**' at the beginning ), but one thing for sure is that I don't need two of them.

I use pycharm to code `python`. My operating system is `macOS Sierra 10.12.6`.

So the problems are:

1. which one of these `python3.6`s should I remove and how(which cmd to use)? 
   (Actually I don't quite understand how those packages work, like Pillow, how they link to python, can they serve for both version of `python3.6`, or can be directed to serve for a specific one, but how?.. And if I uninstall both of two versions and reinstall `python3`, can the packages I installed before work? )
2. other better solutions.

It's a problem that bugged me for a long time, I will appreciate it very much if someone can help me out.